# Can't extend redux connected class, getting super expression either be null

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

what i wanna do is to make a component and connect it to redux(to bring some of redux store props to component), then extend this component and make those redux props available to child component as well(cause they have exactly same props). but i faced a problem:

This is parent class

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { View } from 'react-native'

class UnConnectedManageProductBaseScene extends React.Component {
    public render(){
        return (
            <View/>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {

    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {

    }
}
export const ManageProductBaseScene = connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps
    )(UnConnectedManageProductBaseScene)
```

and this is child class

```
import {   ManageProductBaseScene} from '../ManageProductBaseScene'

export class OwnerManageAuctionScene extends ManageProductBaseScene {
    constructor(props) {
        super()
    }
}
```

when i try to extend `OwnerManageAuctionScene` from redux connected component (`ManageProductBaseScene`) i get error: `Super expression must either be null or a function`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the **props** as a parameter in **super()** like this

```
import {   ManageProductBaseScene} from '../ManageProductBaseScene'

export class OwnerManageAuctionScene extends ManageProductBaseScene {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
}
```